# Error: "value of optional type string not unwrapped"

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm following a tutorial but it was done before the Xcode update so I keep running into some seemingly simple glitches but I do not have enough coding know how to fix them. Anyways, it tells me I have two mistakes there..

-First being "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped did you mean to use '!' or '?'. This comes up beside the .objectId).. I've tried inserting what Xcode recommends but still doesn't work.

-Second error comes up beside the "let user:PFUser =" and it gives me the same error warning as the first one. I've tried to do what Xcode suggests but it comes up with more errors.

//Display Username

```
        var Find:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!

        Find.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:TimelineObject.objectForKey("Publisher")?.objectId)

        Find.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)-> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let user:PFUser = (objects as? NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser

                cell.Username.text = user.username


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change

   ```
   Find.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:TimelineObject.objectForKey("Publisher")?.objectId)
   ```

   to

   ```
   Find.whereKey("objectId", equalTo:TimelineObject.objectForKey("Publisher")!.objectId)
   ```
2. Change

   ```
          let user:PFUser = (objects as? NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser
   ```

   to

   ```
          let user:PFUser = (objects as? NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
   ```

Keep in mind, unwrapping may fail.

Comment: I did exactly that, now where it says Find.whereKey I get the error "cannot invoke 'whereKey' with an argument list of type '(string, equalTo: String?!)' also for #2, i get a warning saying "cast from [AnyObject]? to unrelated type NSArray always fails"

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with PFUser/PFQuery. Someone more familiar with these can easily help you with this.